# Select All checkbox Boxlabel not clickable in internet explorer

Tags: extjs, checkbox, combobox

In the fiddle which I created mentioned below, Select All checkbox is not clickable in internet explorer.It is working correctly in chrome and Firefox
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kn2.

I am using extjs version 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have used `padding: '0, 0, 0, -13'` which is not allowing you to click the checkbox as it is hidden(as per IE).

It seems you don't want to show the default checkbox.So,You can achieve the same functionality using `component` instead of `checkbox`.

```
{
                xtype: 'component',
    //creating unique id because we need handle of this checkbox later
                id: id + 'selectAllChkBox',
            html: '<img class="checkbox-unchecked" style="height:13px;width:13px;"></img>' + ' Select All',
                    listeners: {
        render: function(chkBox){
            chkBox.getEl().on({
                click: function() {

                    combo.expand();
                    if (!allSelected) {
                        combo.select(combo.getStore().getRange());
                        totalCount = combo.getStore().getRange().length;

                        allSelected = true;
                        chkBox.setHtml('<img class="checkbox-checked " style="height:13px;width:13px;"></img>' + ' Deselect All');

                    } else {
                        combo.reset();
                        combo.setValue(null);
                        totalCount = 0;
                        allSelected = false;
                        chkBox.setHtml('<img class="checkbox-unchecked " style="height:13px;width:13px;"></img>' + ' Select All');
                    }               }
            });
        }
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit for an alternative solution and it works fine in 6.01, but it is not working in extjs version 6.2 which we are going to upgrade to in few months. Your solution is fine I think , there is some issue in version 6.2. Could you please suggest some fix?

Comment: Are you talking about the flickering issue in IE when selecting/deslecting all?